Floating shelves (bracket and rail) on one stud?
Three 4-foot rails with brackets supporting four 3-foot shelves (three 1x8, one 1x10) holding books. Middle rail is on a stud, can’t find studs for the others (so just screws in drywall. Screws are 2 inches). Put up today.
Will this hold? If not, how much time do I have before it falls off the wall? Hours, days, weeks?
If this is a terrible idea, what’s the best fix? Toggle bolts? Moving the rails out to the window frame and/or the corner (it’s not quite in the corner) for security? Some kind of board screwed into the wall across studs that I can mount these on? As mentioned, studs are hard to find—not sure if that’s just my shitty stud finder or if it’s plausible there’s studs missing in an exterior wall?
Someone also suggested vertical boards at one or both ends of the shelving, with screws through them into the ends of the shelves. Would that give it enough support to take the weight off the unsecured rails?
Thanks!

If you keep the weight on both sides of stud perfectly balanced all the time, it might hold.  Three foot shelves should hit two studs, if your studs are 16 inch on centre.  Using 1x6 or 3/4 inch plywood to cross the studs and mount shelves to that.

"how much time do I have before it falls off the wall?" This can vary from 'never' for a couple of small paperbacks to 'it's already collapsed' for a full set of law books. A picture can help us pin down that time more accurately. See the question's Edit link, then the mountain icon.

I hope the screws in drywall are at least in expanding anchors.  A screw alone in drywall is worthless.  If your stud spacing is more than 24 inches, this shelf is the least of your problems.

It had better be steel rails,  the aluminium ones are no good for heavy loads like books.

We have no idea, for the reasons mentioned in comments: We don't know your load, load distribution, dynamic loading forces, etc., etc.
That said, you'll dramatically improve your chance of satisfaction if you use proper hollow-wall anchors for the supports not over studs. Screws in drywall are as close to useless as it can be. With a good expanding or toggling anchor you'll add tens of pounds of capacity, at a minimum.
There are many similar questions on this site discussing hollow wall anchors. Do a little reading and pick one that seems appropriate. Don't use basic plastic plugs or threaded screw-in anchors. They're not worth messing with.

I have floating shelves like this.  The rail screws into studs and has welded posts that slide into the wood shelving.  I would not hang one with only one stud connection.  I have two that hold plates and glasses in my kitchen.  I cut the drywall out for the bracket and notched the studs so that it could accommodate a horizontal piece of wood, then screwed into it. I then used duct mastic instead of drywall mud for aesthetics.

The end rails do not need to be right on the  ends of the shelves, but they should definately attach to studs,
